# Home network with FREENAS (NAS)

Tags: networking, routing, freenas

Hello all just working on setting up a network at home with a bunch of network devices and a FREENAS server. My plan is two have my main computer with two nic's one would be used for internet and everything else, the second would be solely for communicating with the freenas. However the other computers must be able to communicate with freenas as well. I have drawn a basic setup of my network and how I plan on setting it up. Just wondering if this would work I have done a lot of reading and this is what I come up with. basically the main computer would have route added (ROUTE ADD) to force the computer to use that card to access freenas. let me know if this would work, or if I am out to lunch. Also if there is a better way to set this up. I am trying to avoid having two subnets.

Picture of my setup:

[CLICK HERE for a Picture of my set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3E5A.jpg)

On the main computer in order to make it use the 2nd NIC to access the FREENAS computer I would add this route:

ROUTE ADD 192.168.1.50 MASK 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.91 IF 192.168.1.91

Would this work or am I completely wrong?

Thanks for any help!